# Getting uncaught error inside our Vue application trying to implement reCAPTCHA

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to import the library `vue-recaptcha` in our Vue application. But I can't get it to work.

Here are our files:

**main.js**

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import "./style.css";
import App from "./App.vue";
import { VueRecaptchaPlugin } from "vue-recaptcha/head";

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(VueRecaptchaPlugin, {
  v2SiteKey: "6LdMAEAlAAAAAGODdzEfTAWfrGdO3CyzrCKS_R_E",
});
const instanceOfAppComponent = app.mount("#app");
```

**App.vue**

```
<script setup>
import Contact from "./layouts/Contact.vue";
import { useRecaptchaProvider } from "vue-recaptcha";
useRecaptchaProvider();
</script>

<template>
  <Contact />
</template>
```

**Contact.vue**

```
<template>
  <form>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" v-model="name" />

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" v-model="email" />

    <Checkbox />

    <button type="submit" @click.prevent="submitForm">Submit</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import { Checkbox } from "vue-recaptcha";

export default {
  components: {
    Checkbox: Checkbox,
  },
};
</script>
```

In the console we are getting following message:

```
Uncaught Error: useRecaptcha() is called without provider.
```

Does somebody see why we are getting this message? Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: This kind of errors can be caused by dupe copies of a lib. In this case it's probably caused by the mix of "vue-recaptcha" and "vue-recaptcha/head". Stick to one of them, unless you're sure that it doesn't contain the exports that you need

Comment: @EstusFlask I still get the same when changing "vue-recaptcha/head" to  "vue-recaptcha" message.

Comment: Try to use it in nested comp instead of App if it makes a difference